# Как поменять содержимое библиотеку js?

Tags: javascript, python, django, библиотеки

На данный момент у меня библиотека вставлена таким образом:

```
script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/tablesort.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/sorts/tablesort.number.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/sorts/tablesort.date.js"></script>
        <script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/sorts/tablesort.dotsep.js"></script>
```

Мне нужно поменять библиотеку с датами, так как не устраивает содержимое. Необходимо дополнить его.
Как это сделать?

Нужно вставить это

```
(function(){
  var parseDate = function(date) {
    date = date.replace(/\-/g, '/');
    date = date.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2,4})/, '$3-$2-$1'); // format before getTime
    
    date = date.replace(/января/i, 'Jan');
    date = date.replace(/февраля/i, 'Feb');
    date = date.replace(/марта/i, 'Mar');
    date = date.replace(/апреля/i, 'Apr');
    date = date.replace(/мая/i, 'May');
    date = date.replace(/июня/i, 'Jun');
    date = date.replace(/июля/i, 'Jul');
    date = date.replace(/августа/i, 'Aug');
    date = date.replace(/сентября/i, 'Sep');
    date = date.replace(/октября/i, 'Oct');
    date = date.replace(/ноября/i, 'Nov');
    date = date.replace(/декабря/i, 'Dec');
    return new Date(date).getTime()  -1;
  };

  Tablesort.extend('date', function(item) {
    return (
      item.search(/(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\.?\,?\s*/i) !== -1 
      item.search(/\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{2,4}/) !== -1 
      item.search(/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)/i) !== -1 
      item.search(/(Января|Февраля|Марта|Апреля|Мая|Июня|Июля|Августа|Сентября|Октября|Ноября|Декабря)/i) !== -1
    ) && !isNaN(parseDate(item));
  }, function(a, b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();

    return parseDate(b) - parseDate(a);
  });
}());
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Не понял, зачем вам менять сожержимое библиотеки, если вы можете просто объявить свою ф-ию и работать с ней?

Comment: А как правильно объявлять свою функцию? Что писать в html ? <script type="text/javascript" src=static/othcet.js"></script> ?

Comment: `import`-ом и `export`-ом самый лучший способ. Ну или поместите объявление ф-ии выше всех других своих скриптов и потом в других местах, просто обращайтесь к нему по названию

Comment: <script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/tablesort.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/sorts/tablesort.number.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/sorts/tablesort.dotsep.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src=static/othcet.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    new Tablesort(document.getElementById('table-id'));
});
</script>    Вот весь код, как тут обращаться?

Comment: Просто пишете название своей ф-ии. После `new Tablesort`

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать как это всё должно быть. Я просто js не знаю совсем. Что нужно писать в js,html?

Comment: Метод [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) предназначен для поиска и замены подстроки в строке, а чтобы поменять русские месяцы на английские больше подойдёт двухмерный массив в первом измерении будут русские названия, а во втором английские.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто объявите ф-ию раньше своих скриптов, но позже подключённых библиотек и дальше в своих скриптах обращайтесь к нему просто по названию:

```html
<script>
  function doSomething() {
    return 'doSomething';
  }
</script>

<script>
  const x = doSomething();
  
  console.log(x);
</script>
```